# Why do I get ten points for an upvoted answer rather than 5?

Tags: discussion, voting

Forgive me because I'm still unclear on how things work on SE, and this is a point that I may just be confused about. But it seems that when a question or answer gets an upvote on Politics.SE, I get a little green "+10" badge (that makes me feel good about myself.) But when a question or answer on another board gets an upvote, I only get a "+5" (which makes me feel good about myself but slightly less so.)

Is the +10 per upvote a thing specific to Politics.SE or is some other mechanic at work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be mistaken.  A user receives +5 rep when their question is upvoted and +10 when their answer is upvoted.

This is true here on Politics.SE (see our [tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)) as well as other sites, such as SciFi.SE (their [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Additionally, rep is "batched" on the navbar. So you may have +5 rep if some combination of events net out to a +5. For example, maybe you have +10 (from an upvote to your question) but -5 from downvoting others' answers. The navbar will display an alert for the net change of +5 rep.

Answer (score 3):

Originally questions gave +10 as well, but that was [changed for SO (pre-SE network) in 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/19/important-reputation-rule-changes/)

> In other words, we’re rebalancing a bit to favor answers.

So you're not getting more rep for answers, you're getting less for questions. More a philosophy than anything